# Preview not changing device to iPhone SE when using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, preview

I am new to SwiftUI and I was trying to change my preview device to iPhone SE but the device does not change. When I update the text "Hello, world!" to something else in the ContentView, it does show the updated text on the preview device. The device is current the default device provided when I created a new project using SwiftUI. I am currently using Xcode version 12.0.1 and below is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone SE"))
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Just change the targeted simulator in Xcode?

Comment: That works but I want also want to change it using the ContentView_Previews since I am learning something new.

Comment: This question had an answer accepted 2 years ago

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74493050/1442541

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to specify full designated name, like below (because there is 1st generation also)

```
ContentView().previewDevice("iPhone SE (2nd generation)")
```

the full list can be viewed in in Terminal as

```
$ xcrun simctl list devicetypes
```

Comment: But how can I avoid adding that in every view?
Is it possible to change the default simulatr Xcode 13 does preview in?

Comment: @esbenr Please see my answer.Xcode automatically chooses a available preview device based on your currently selected run destination.

Answer (score 12):

All you need to specify designated name given by apple:

```
YourContentView().previewDevice(DeviceName.iPhone_11_Pro.rawValue)
```

---

To get all names, you may use this DeviceName Custom enum.

```
 enum DeviceName: String, CaseIterable {
    case iPod_touch_5th_generation = "iPod touch (5th generation)"
    case iPod_touch_6th_generation = "iPod touch (6th generation)"
    case iPod_touch_7th_generation = "iPod touch (7th generation)"
    case iPhone_4 = "iPhone 4"
    case iPhone_4s = "iPhone 4s"
    case iPhone_5 = "iPhone 5"
    case iPhone_5c = "iPhone 5c"
    case iPhone_5s = "iPhone 5s"
    case iPhone_6 = "iPhone 6"
    case iPhone_6_Plus = "iPhone 6 Plus"
    case iPhone_6s = "iPhone 6s"
    case iPhone_6s_Plus = "iPhone 6s Plus"
    case iPhone_7 = "iPhone 7"
    case iPhone_7_Plus = "iPhone 7 Plus"
    case iPhone_8 = "iPhone 8"
    case iPhone_8_Plus = "iPhone 8 Plus"
    case iPhone_X = "iPhone X"
    case iPhone_XS = "iPhone XS"
    case iPhone_XS_Max = "iPhone XS Max"
    case iPhone_XR = "iPhone XR"
    case iPhone_11 = "iPhone 11"
    case iPhone_11_Pro = "iPhone 11 Pro"
    case iPhone_11_Pro_Max = "iPhone 11 Pro Max"
    case iPhone_12_mini = "iPhone 12 mini"
    case iPhone_12 = "iPhone 12"
    case iPhone_12_Pro = "iPhone 12 Pro"
    case iPhone_12_Pro_Max = "iPhone 12 Pro Max"
    case iPhone_13_mini = "iPhone 13 mini"
    case iPhone_13 = "iPhone 13"
    case iPhone_13_Pro = "iPhone 13 Pro"
    case iPhone_13_Pro_Max = "iPhone 13 Pro Max"
    case iPhone_SE = "iPhone SE"
    case iPhone_SE_2nd_generation = "iPhone SE (2nd generation)"
    case iPhone_SE_3rd_generation = "iPhone SE (3rd generation)"
    case iPad_2 = "iPad 2"
    case iPad_3rd_generation = "iPad (3rd generation)"
    case iPad_4th_generation = "iPad (4th generation)"
    case iPad_5th_generation = "iPad (5th generation)"
    case iPad_6th_generation = "iPad (6th generation)"
    case iPad_7th_generation = "iPad (7th generation)"
    case iPad_8th_generation = "iPad (8th generation)"
    case iPad_9th_generation = "iPad (9th generation)"
    case iPad_Air = "iPad Air"
    case iPad_Air_2 = "iPad Air 2"
    case iPad_Air_3rd_generation = "iPad Air (3rd generation)"
    case iPad_Air_4th_generation = "iPad Air (4th generation)"
    case iPad_Air_5th_generation = "iPad Air (5th generation)"
    case iPad_mini = "iPad mini"
    case iPad_mini_2 = "iPad mini 2"
    case iPad_mini_3 = "iPad mini 3"
    case iPad_mini_4 = "iPad mini 4"
    case iPad_mini_5th_generation = "iPad mini (5th generation)"
    case iPad_mini_6th_generation = "iPad mini (6th generation)"
    case iPad_Pro_9_7_inch = "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)"
    case iPad_Pro_10_5_inch = "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)"
}
```

Comment: It need to be used like this .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: DeviceName.iPhone_13.rawValue))