# PreviewDevice not showing up in preview

Tags: swiftui, preview

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 11"))
    }
}
```

However, the device is not shown in the preview. I ran "`xcrun simctl list devicetypes`" in terminal which does show the simulator. Is this normal behavior or am I missing something. The goal is that I want to show how the app looks with the iPhone resolution. I am using xCode 13.

[image]

Comment: You aren't missing anything. I would try cleaning, deleting derived data and a restart. That never hurts, other than build time.

Comment: That's true. Restarting didn't help. I guess if you say that this is the way the go, my editor is just broken.

Comment: Btw, is your deployment target includes iOS?

Comment: That is the answer! It was on macOS not iOS. Because I am building a shared app. Is there a way you can have both? For Preview.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have meet same issue at Xcode Version 14.1 (14B47b).

In my case ,this is because an unavailable simulator model has been selected like "iPhone 11",Xcode automatically chooses a available preview device based on your currently selected run destination.

Like this:

(selected iPhone SE2 but automatically chooses iPhone14 Pro)
[image]

Press control and option, click `previewDevice`, and then select an available model in the inspector can fix it：

(iPhone 14 selected, preview shows as expected)
[image]

If there is no model you want in these options, you can add it in the menu Window -> Devices and Simulators first.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: In my case Preview Device is just a text box to type in. It's not a dropdown like yours.

Answer (score 0):

This first line wasn't enough all 3 lines before Xcode 15 SwiftUI Preview changed.

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
ContentView()
        .previewDevice("iPhone 15")
        .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 15"))
        .previewDisplayName("iPhone 15")
    }
}
```

and deleted this

```
#Preview {
ContentView()
}
```